# OPENLDAP as a proxy of other ldap

Tags: proxy, ldap, openldap

I don't know if it's possible or not.
In our compagny we have a main ldap who contain all employees.
I wanted to custom it but it's no possible.

So the idea is to create an new ldap based on Openldap.

Is an openldap can act as a proxy for the main ldap for users
(user/password are stored in the main ldap compagny) and group would be defined inside it. Groups will contain users from the main ldap.
Do you think it's possible and how ?

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways to accomplish this, but configuring the OpenLDAP server as a [translucent proxy](https://www.openldap.org/doc/admin24/overlays.html#Translucent%20Proxy) and overriding/adding attributes from the other LDAP server seems like the most straight-forward approach.